# Show back button without navigation view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have the scheme: `UITabBarViewController` (with 3 tabs).
In all that tabs I don't want to show navigation menu on top.
And from the first tab, I want to push another view controller from button click that will have "back" button (and top toolbar with "cancel")

I tried some ways - in `storyboard` with push segue - no back button.
Probably because i don't have navigation view controller, so my navigation stack is empty.

Programmatically:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddCoinTableViewController") as! AddCoinTableViewController
self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

If I embed tabs in navigation controller, then I have top toolbar (which I don't want).

Any ideas how to make it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't achieve navigation functionality without using `UINavigationController`. I mean you have to do all animation kind of stuff on your own, and I think that's not a good idea. Rather than that, you can use `UINavigationController`, and if you don't want to show `navigationBar` at some viewController, than do as follows for those view controllers.

```
override func viewWillApear() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
Small changes to code:
I added in viewWillAppear because when coming back viewDidLoad() not called.

Comment: `You can't achieve navigationBar functionality without using UINavigationController` is incorrect.. You can use `UINavigatonBar` as a sub-view in your controller and add back buttons to it if you wish.. Or just create your own back button as a sub-view..

Comment: @Brandon you are right, but UINavigatonBar will be displayed if and only if your parent viewcontroller has UINavigationController.

Comment: @Brandon even I put that " I mean you have to do all animation kind of stuff at your own, and I think that's not a good idea"

Comment: even if we are not using UINavigationController, `self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)` will present viewcontroller rather than push to stack.

Comment: @SharadPaghadal; Who told you that? I ended up adding an answer that does exactly what OP wanted. While I did use custom animations, it's not hard and it isn't a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed the navigation controller at your first tab controller (or any you want), and hide it at the controllers you don't want on their viewDidLoad like this:

`self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true`

Doing this, you will be able to see the back Button at the controllers you pushed and didn't hide the navigationBar.

Make sure you push the controller using the navigation controller like this:

`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER, animated: true)`

Answer (score 2):

The below code will allow you to create your own Navigation handling class and have the "push" "pop" animation that `UINavigationController` has.. You can create a new project, copy paste the below into `ViewController.swift` and see for yourself..

Now you can give any `UIViewController` navigation controller abilities..

```
import UIKit

class NavigationHandler : NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UINavigationBarDelegate {
    private var isPresenting: Bool = false
    private weak var controller: UIViewController?

    init(controller: UIViewController) {
        super.init()

        self.controller = controller
        controller.transitioningDelegate = self

        let navigationBar = UINavigationBar()
        controller.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            navigationBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.leftAnchor),
            navigationBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.rightAnchor),
            navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
        ])
        navigationBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        navigationBar.delegate = self

        let item = UINavigationItem(title: controller.title ?? "")
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(onBackButton(button:)))

        item.leftBarButtonItems = [barButton]
        navigationBar.setItems([item], animated: true)
    }

    func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
        return .topAttached
    }

    @objc
    private func onBackButton(button: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.controller?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.isPresenting = true;
        return self;
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.isPresenting = false;
        return self;
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.25;
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let duration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        let fromController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)
        let toController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        if self.isPresenting {
            let frame = fromController!.view.frame
            containerView.addSubview(toController!.view)
            toController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x + frame.width, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {

                fromController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x - frame.size.width, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)

                toController?.view.frame = frame

            }, completion: { (completed) in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })
        }
        else {
            let frame = fromController!.view.frame
            containerView.insertSubview(toController!.view, at: 0)
            toController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x - frame.size.width, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {

                fromController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x + frame.width, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)

                toController?.view.frame = frame

            }, completion: { (completed) in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

View Controllers for testing:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

    private var navigationHandler: NavigationHandler?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Push Controller", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45.0),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0)
        ])

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onPush(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc
    private func onPush(button: UIButton) {
        let child = ChildViewController()
        self.navigationHandler = NavigationHandler(controller: child)
        self.present(child, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```